# Why is my value not being updated? useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm using useState hook to update the values of my inputs inside a form. This is the object I'm using in my useState hook:

```
const [values, setValues ] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    confirmEmail: '',
    message: ''
  });
```

Then I have an array with the inputs and there type id and other fields:

```
const inputs = [
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Email'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'confirmEmail',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Email'
    }
]
```

I have the following handleChange function to update the state of my values which replaces the `name` property of my object with the value I enter in the input.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}) 
    console.log(values)
  }
```

This is my complete component so that you can see what I'm rendering:

ContactForm.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import SubmitBtn from '../atoms/SubmitBtn';
import FormInput from '../molecules/FormInput'

const ContactForm = () => {

  const [values, setValues ] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    confirmEmail: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const inputs = [
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Email'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'confirmEmail',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Email'
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      name: 'message',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Message'
    }
  ]

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello world');
  }

  const onChange= (e) => {
    setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}) 
    console.log(values)
  }    

  return (
    <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {inputs.map((input)=>(
        <FormInput 
        key={input.id} 
        {...input} 
        value={values[inputs.name]} 
        onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
      <SubmitBtn/>         
    </form>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

FormInput.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import './FormInput.css';
import { Input } from '../atoms/Input';

const FormInput = (props) => {

  const { id, onChange, ...inputProps } = props;

  return (
    <div className='formInput'>
        {/* <label htmlFor="">Username</label> */}
        <Input {...inputProps} onChange={onChange}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormInput
```

Input.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Input = (props) => {

    const { id, onChange, ...inputProps } = props;

  return (
    <input {...inputProps} onChange={onchange} />
  )
}
```

I tried making a console.log(values) to see the values as they change but it just shows it one time in the console and all the values are empty. I tried doing a console.log inside the handleChange function as well as outside.

```
Object { name: "", lastname: "", email: "", confirmEmail: "", message: "" }
```

Comment: Because you check too early. How _could_ the value have changed before `console.log(values)`, given you carefully don't mutate the original value and certainly haven't reassigned to the (`const`!) variable?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i already tried also doing a console log after the handleChange function? is that what your are saying? I dont understand what are you trying to say about mutatin the orginal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two things to fix here:

a. In Input.js ,

```
 const { id, onChange, ...inputProps } = props;

return (
    <input {...inputProps} onChange={onChange} />
```

Here, the onChange in input tag was onchange instead of onChange.

b. In ContactForm.js,

```
return (
    <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {inputs.map((input)=>(
        <FormInput 
        key={input.id} 
        {...input} 
        value={values[input.name]} 
        onChange={onChange}
        />
      ))}
      <SubmitBtn/>         
    </form>
  )
}
```

Here, the value in FormInput was value={values[inputs.name] instead of value={values[input.name]}. Note the 's' in input.

Copy these codes, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async - you can't just `console.log` the updated version right after you fire the setter because execution of the setter is put on the call stack after the console log. Try a `useEffect` to console log every time `values` changes to see if a change is being triggered.

`useEffect(() => console.log(values), [values])`

Or just render the values to the bottom of your form temporarily for debugging purposes and you should see them update when a new value is added.

Comment: I cant even write somenthing in my inputs and im getting the following error. `  You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. ` Im passing my props from my form to the child component `<FormInput/>` and from here to the grandchild component `<Input/>`